# Numbers which have a multiple whose digit sum is less than the digit sum of themselves

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are infinitely many numbers which have at least one multiple whose digit sum is less than that of the number itself : $$2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13$$ and son on.

Likewise there are infinitely many which don´t, all powers of 10, for example.

> $1.$ Are there arbitrarly long sets of consecutive numbers *each* of which has at least one multiple whose digit sum is less than the digit sum of the number itself?

> $2.$ What about arbitrarly long sets of consecutive numbers *none* of which has at least one multiple whose digit sum is less than the digit sum of the number itself?

Comment: We need an efficient criterion for a number to have or have not the property. I do not think this will be easy : Consider $$1234602$$ for which the smallest multiple doing the job is $$20000003002110$$

Comment: I'd conjecture that only finitely many prime numbers do not satisfy your property. Then, if 2. is true, you have to look at consecutive composite numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer :

> Claim : There are arbitary long ranges such that every number in the range has the desired property

Proof :

Fix a positive integer $k$ and choose an integer $s$ such that $$4s>9(k+1)$$ holds.

Then, every number emerging by writing down $s$ digits $5$ , followed by a $0$ and then an arbitary $k$-digit number will be a number for which doubling will decrease the digitsum because the $5's$ turn into $1's$ "overcompensating" the maximum possible increase by doubling the $k$-digit number.

Therefore, we have established $9\cdot 10^{k-1}$ consecutive numbers surely having the desired property. Since $k$ was arbitary, we have proven the claim.